# Type inference issue in Pylance for a variable of Union type

Tags: python, numpy, type-hinting, python-typing, pylance

I'm writing a function with different behaviors depending on whether the argument is a scalar or a NumPy array. However, I'm getting the following two typing errors that I don't know how to solve:

1. `Expression of type "generic | bool | int | float | complex | str | bytes | memoryview" cannot be assigned to return type "float" Type "generic | bool | int | float | complex | str | bytes | memoryview" cannot be assigned to type "float" "bytes" is incompatible with "float"` PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
2. `"__ getitem __" method not defined on type "float"` PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues**.

How can I let Pylance know that if the code reaches the expressions inside the `if` statement `x` should be a `float`, and if it reaches the `else` expresssions `x` should be a NumPy array?

Example code:

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt


def func(x: float | npt.NDArray[np.float64]) -> float:
    if np.isscalar(x):
        return x     # Error 1)
    else:
        return x[0]  # Error 2)


def main():
    x = 0.4
    print(func(x))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Which line is the first error occurring on?

Comment: If necessary, try `cast`. Or use `if/assert` `isinstance`.

Comment: The first error is occurring on "return x" and the second one on return x[0]

Comment: Are you sure this is the full code to reproduce your problem? At least with Mypy I am not getting that first error. And I don't understand why you would get an error there because you did not define a return type for `func`. That means it should fall back to `Any`, which means returning `x` should be fine. Or did you forget the `func` return type annotation?

Comment: I did forget to add the return type annotation for `func`. I just edited the question.

Comment: Using one function to distinguish between a `foo` and a  sequence of `foo`s is a bit of an anti pattern in the first place. I would define `def func(x: npt.NDArray[np.float64]) -> float: ...`, make the *caller* responsible for packing something that isn't already such an array *in* a suitable array, and then ensuring that the first element is converted to a `float`.

Comment: Also, `float` and `float64` are two different types. `mypy` doesn't know that they represent essentially the same data. `x[0]`, if it works, has type `np.float64`, not `float`.

Comment: Thank you, chepner. It's true that `np.float64`  is not the same type as `float`. But shouldn't they at least be compatible? I found in another question that `np.float64` doesn't inherit from `float` so `Pylance` or `mypy` can't know they're compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to add an `assert` or a `cast` to force it to be treated as a float. Any of the following will work:

```
assert isinstance(x, float)
x = cast(float, x)
x = float(x)  # type: ignore
```

All together:

```
def func(x: float | npt.NDArray[np.float64]) -> float:
    if np.isscalar(x):
        assert isinstance(x, float)
        return x
    else:
        assert not isinstance(x, float)
        return x[0]
```

...although, more direct would have been:

```
def func(x: float | npt.NDArray[np.float64]) -> float:
    return x if isinstance(x, float) else x[0]
```

...unless you're relying upon `np.isscalar` to do something other than what these type signatures suggest.

Comment: Thank You. I was not relying on `np.isscalar` for anything special, so using `isinstance` instead solved the problem.